# $ \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{x \sin(t-\tau)} d\tau $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, exponential-function

### Question

I am working on a problem that involves the integral

$$
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{x \sin(t-\tau)} d\tau
$$

where $t$ is a parameter and $x$ is a constant. This integral appears in a specific context of my research related to Electromagnetic. I am looking for ways to derive this integral, either to find a closed-form solution or a simplification that could be more easily evaluated numerically.

### Background

The integral is intriguing because it combines exponential functions with the trigonometric sine function, where the sine function includes a difference in its argument. The bounds of the integral cover a full period of the sine function, which suggests that there might be symmetrical properties or periodicity that could be exploited in the derivation.

### Attempted Approaches

1. **Direct Integration:** I initially attempted to integrate directly using standard techniques but did not arrive at a simplification that was helpful.
2. **Change of Variable:** Considering a change of variable such as $\theta = t - \tau$ did not significantly simplify the integration, possibly due to my approach in handling the limits of integration or the periodic nature of the sine function.
3. **Fourier Series and Euler's Formula:** I also considered decomposing the sine function using Euler's formula or exploring Fourier series representations, thinking it might reveal a more manageable form for integration. However, I'm unsure of how to proceed effectively in this direction.

### Questions

1. **Has anyone encountered a similar integral, and how did you approach its derivation?**
2. **Are there specific change of variable techniques or trigonometric identities that would simplify this integral?**
3. **Could Fourier series or Euler's formula provide a pathway to either a closed-form solution or a more accessible numerical evaluation?**
4. **Any recommendations on literature or resources that tackle similar integrals would be highly appreciated.**

Thank you for any insights or guidance you can provide!

Comment: $$ \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{x \sin(t-\tau)} d\tau = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{x \sin(\tau)} d\tau=2\pi I_0(x) $$

Comment: @Quanto thanks, should not be a function of t?

Comment: I think it is not bessel exactly, becauae after change of veriable the integral limits doesnot match with bessel.

Comment: @AlirezaGhazavi. The answer is correct: $2 \pi  I_0(x)$ .Solution  is independent of the parameter t.

Comment: @AlirezaGhazavi: notice that $$\int^\pi_{-\pi}e^{x\sin t}\,dt=
\int^{\pi/2}_{-3\pi/2}e^{x\sin(t+\pi/2)}\,dt=\int^{\pi/2}_{-3\pi/2}e^{x\cos t}\,dt=\int^{\pi}_{-\pi}e^{x\cos t}\,dt
$$ The last equality follows from periodicity.

Comment: @Mittens Thanks a lot.